# How to add a folder to JBOSS EAP 6 Classpath

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I tried below approach, but didnt succeed to retrieve my properties file into inputstream.

https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath

**My project** : https://github.com/manojp1988/Learning/tree/master/Sample

**Jboss folder structure:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add your module to your application classpath (step 3 of [How to put an external file in the classpath](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath)):

> Add your module to your application classpath in a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
> <jboss-deployment-structure>  
>   <deployment>  
>     <dependencies>  
>       <module name="com.mycompany.configuration" />  
>     </dependencies>  
>   </deployment>  
> </jboss-deployment-structure>
> ```
>
> This file must be placed either in the `META-INF` directory of your
>   EAR file or the `WEB-INF` directory of your WAR file. See [Class Loading in AS7](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7) for more information.
>
> or add your module to your application classpath using a `MANIFEST.MF`
>   entry:
>
> ```
> Manifest-Version: 1.0
> Dependencies: com.mycompany.configuration
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I just figure out the issue.

If I put my jboss-deployment-structure.xml in WEB-INF of WAR, i have to specify  and put my dependencies inside it.

If I put my jboss-deployment-structure.xml in META-INF of EAR, i have to specify  and put my dependencies inside it.